# Помогите с пояснением непонятных символов в php

Tags: php, символы

Добрый вечер.

Столкнулся вот с такими записями в коде:

```
isset($aRow["columns"][$id])? $aRow["columns"][$id] : $aRow["data"][$id]
$val <> ''? $val:'&nbsp;'
```

Может кто пояснить, что означают эти символы: `<>` `?` `:`

Исходя из языка Делфи, если я правильно помню, то `<>` - это отрицание или неравенство.

Прошу у знающих и бывалых программистов помощи в пояснении данных двух строк.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение написано с помощью тернарного оператора, всё [описано в справке по php](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php).

Выражение `$val <> ''? $val:'&nbsp;'` перводится так:
Если $val не равно пустоте, тогда ничего не меняем, если в $val пусто, тогда подставляем символ пробела. Но вообще более комфортнее для чтения пишется так:

```
$var == '' ? '&nbsp;' : $val;
```

То же самое классикой:

```
if($var == '') {
  $var = '&nbsp;';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот кусок кода

```
$val <> ''? $val:'&nbsp;'
```

можно заменить таким кодом

```
insert_space($val)
```

и определение функции

```
function insert_space($val) {
   if ($val <> '') {
     return '';
   } else {
     return '&nbsp;';
   }
}
```

вот только я не помню, в php используется `<>` или `!=`.

Comment: Ну в php обычно всегда использую != отрицание, это <>, я так понимаю, тоже отрицание? 

То есть по тому, что вы расписали, в данной строке написано что, если $val не равен пустой сроке, то возвращаем пустую строку, иначе возвращаем пробельный символ. Тем самым ? знак в данной строке является оператором условия if. Верно я понимаю?

Comment: `?:` - это так называемый тернарный оператор. Да, он работает как if, просто он умеет возвращать результат.

По поводу `<>` - да, в php [оно так](http://www.php.su/learnphp/operators/?compar).

Comment: @KeH192 Такой оператор сравнения `<>` php-разработчиками не используется. Как правильно заметил @KoVadim, общепринято использовать `!=`, т.е. нестрогое сравнение. [Можете посмотреть](http://ideone.com/24pIGC), какие значение под это условие попадают, а какие нет.

Answer (score 1):

`<>` - более старый аналог более современного `!==`

Плюс его понимали разработчики с других языков, где `!==` не прижился или вообще не реализован.